# How to Correctly Populate Firebase UICollectionView Data?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview, firebase-realtime-database

So I have been messing with this view controller for the last 6+ hours to no conclusive avail. Basically I have a UICollectionView (chat log) pushed onto the screen after clicking on a UICollectionViewCell from the previous view (contact thread list). Whenever the new view comes up, zero messages come up, and print(messages.count) yields a 0. The annoying thing is I can type messages into the text field and hit send, which then sends the message to the online database correctly. Can somebody tell me how to get the messages in my online database to populate the view correctly? (Or at least what I did wrong?)

**Initial Code:**

```
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var messages: [FIRDataSnapshot]! = []
private var _refHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle!
var storageRef: FIRStorageReference! // For images
var clientTable: UICollectionView! // For collectionview editing
var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Register cell classes
    clientTable?.registerClass(ChatLogCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true

    // Access root of database
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    // Access root of storage (for non-text media)
    storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().referenceForURL("gs://remedy-9403f.appspot.com")
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.messages.removeAll() //possible problem?
    // Listen for new messages in the Firebase database
    _refHandle = self.ref.child("messages").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
        self.messages.append(snapshot)
        print(self.messages) //temp
        print(self.messages.count) //temp
        self.clientTable?.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: self.messages.count - 1, inSection: 1)])
    })
    self.clientTable?.reloadData()
}
```

**Cell code:**

```
override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // Dequeue cell
    let cell = clientTable.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChatLogCollectionCell

    print(self.messages.count) //temp

    // Unpack message from Firebase DataSnapshot
    let messageSnapshot: FIRDataSnapshot! = self.messages[indexPath.row]
    let message = messageSnapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>!
    let name = message[Constants.MessageFields.name] as String!
    if let imageUrl = message[Constants.MessageFields.imageUrl] {
        if imageUrl.hasPrefix("gs://") {
            FIRStorage.storage().referenceForURL(imageUrl).dataWithMaxSize(INT64_MAX){ (data, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error downloading: \(error)")
                    return
                }
                cell.imageMessageView.image = UIImage.init(data: data!)
            }
        } else if let url = NSURL(string:imageUrl), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
            cell.imageMessageView.image = UIImage.init(data: data)
        }
        cell.messageTextView.text = "sent by: \(name)"
        print("Attempted text audit") //temp
    } else {
        let text = message[Constants.MessageFields.text] as String!
        cell.messageTextView.text = name + ": " + text
        print("Attempted text audit") //temp
        cell.imageMessageView.image = UIImage(named: "")
        if let photoUrl = message[Constants.MessageFields.photoUrl], url = NSURL(string:photoUrl), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
            cell.imageMessageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }

    // Bubble
    if let messageText = message[Constants.MessageFields.text] as String! {
        let size = CGSizeMake(250, 1000)
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading.union(.UsesLineFragmentOrigin)
        let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: messageText).boundingRectWithSize(size, options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18)], context: nil)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: A few things, first off, Firebase queries are asynchronous so when you call for messages.count, it might still be 0 (because the code does not wait for the database call to complete). Secondly, you should not be doing database queries / inserts inside a view controller (it's bad coding practice)

Comment: How would I wait for the database call to complete?

What is the preferred location of database query implementation?

Comment: So using some more print lines I have discovered that `self.messages.removeAll()` was making the array report 0 even after the query and data reload. I have also found that each entry in the array is the entire messages snapshot (so a giant duplicate).

Comment: Normally I write all of my database queries and insertions inside a file called `Database.swift` and then just call it when I need it. It makes the Controller code look a lot cleaner and also you would be separating your "Views" and your "Persistence" layers. I get around the asynchronous database by making a loading screen and getting all my data there (but I'm sure there are far better ways of doing it).